# LIMIT before DISTINCT

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT no, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL 
FROM ar_test 
GROUP BY no 
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```

This code works fine

So I have this column `no` and it holds numbers from 0 to 36
And I have a lot of rows. So this SQL groups them in single 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 .... 36 and in `TOTAL` gives me the count of every 0 to 36 number. It looks like this : 
0 - is 40 times in the table 
1 - is 35 times 
2 - 15 
3 - 14 etc... 
This code counts all my rows.

So I need to add limit, I want to count the last 100 rows only and check it out their count. 
If I add `LIMIT 7` at the end of my SQL code for example. It won't work that way cuz it will give me the count from number 0 to 6...
First I need to select (limit) the last 7 rows, and after that to use my type of code and count them.

Comment: 1. Distinct on a GROUP(ed) BY column is useless. 2. The last 100 rows, last by what (order by something ?). 3. What's your dbms ? I would say MySql if you talk about LIMIT, but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a subquery:

```
select a.no, count(*) total 
  from (
        select no from test order by no desc limit 5
       ) a
  group by a.no 
  order by total desc;
```

Here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7ca0f/12

Comment: And, as @Raphaël Althaus has said, distinct is useless.

Comment: I want to order by the count :S How can I print the count in PHP

Answer (score 1):

> I want to count the last 100 rows only and check it out their count.

I assume you've some kind of id in there that you can use in a subquery:

```
select no, count(*)
from (select no from table order by id desc limit 100) as subset
group by no
```

Comment: But I don't have the TOTAL (count of the number) :(
check my code :/

Comment: Err… I strongly suggest you rephrase your question then, because as things stand it's not the slightest bit clear what you want exactly. (And that, if anything, is why I actually quoted the bit that seemed like an actual question.)